# Pass password for download script

Tags: bash, passwords

I'm downloading huge files and have a python downloading script. Since the data are to huge to be stored in their original format, I only download a couple of years, process them, then delete the original before I download the next few years. For every set of years I have a separate download script and I just build a quick bash script to run them

```
#!/bin/bash
python download_1901-1909.py
## processing, delete
python download_1910-1919.py
## processing, delete
python download_1920-1929.py
## processing, delete

[...]
```

For the download scipt, I have to type in a password. I know it's is possible to do some automatic password passing with spawn, but I couldn't make it work. Trying the spawn thing does this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn python download_1901-1909.py
expect "Password:" 
send "mypassword"
interact
```

yields

```
 sh test.sh 
 test.sh: line 2: spawn: command not found
 couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
 test.sh: line 4: send: command not found
 test.sh: line 5: interact: command not found
```

How can I pass a password to a python download script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is trying to solve your question of finishing what you need, not the question of executing a `#!/usr/bin/expect`, which may be what you are asking.*

You may try to use the `-c` param of `expect` inline.

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "spawn python download-1901_1909.py; expect \"assword\"; send \"mypassword\r\n\"; interact"
expect -c "spawn python download-1910_1919.py; expect \"assword\"; send \"mypassword\r\n\"; interact" 
# and the remaining, similarly
```

Note:

1. Your `send` part may need to send the `\r\n` to "simulate" the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key of finishing enter the password.
2. You may use `sed` within a `for` to simply the lines.
3. "assword" is to prevent the case of first letter of that word, "Password" vs "password", for some portability.